# Multi-Screen Setup with only one fixed Workspace, the opposite of "workspaces only on primary display"

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, workspaces, cinnamon

I have a three monitor setup using Cinnamon (+gnome apps). I know the option “workspaces only on primary display”, but I want the opposite.

I want to have one fixed screen (could be the primary one) and the other two should span and have workspaces.

Is this possible?

I know that I can tell a single windows to show up on each workspace - but that is not really what I want.

Comment: Hello! are you on ubuntu? kubuntu? lubuntu? xubuntu? ubuntu-mate? you didn't specify. you also didn't specify which version. both of these change how the settings menu looks alot. even if your settings menu is in gnome 3 or cinnamon, which, using what you said isn't clear either. I could tell you to press button "X", and you'd respond that you don't have button "X". lastly and most importantly, your question isn't clear. I too have multiple monitors and use workspaces, yet I don't understand what you want. could you perhaps edit your question, maybe add an illustration to your idea?

Comment: Sorry for beein not precise enough. I wanted to be very general because it's obviously the same principle for let's say a 4.monitor setup. And the options available are the same for gnome and cinnamon. Currently I run LinuxMint19 but thinking about to switch to Ubuntu on my Laptop. So it will be a brand new installation with latest version. I want to connect 2 external Monitors to the laptop. The laptop monitor should be a fixed workspace (does not switch) the 2 connected monitors should switch workspaces simultaneously.